# Find the value of $n$ where

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

Let $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ where $x,y$ are natural no.s, and $f(1)=3$

Then find $n$ if $\sum_1^nf(n)=120$

Comment: $f(x)$ can be $a^x$  and $3=f(1)=a$

Comment: I have edited this to give what I think is the sum you were looking for. I would start by using $f(2)=f(1+1)$ and computing that using the formula. Then more generally try $f(n+1)$ to see what is happening.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: why not $f(x)=ax+b$?

Comment: $f(x) = ax + b$ doesn't satisfy $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ unless $a=b=0$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

By induction it can be shown that $f(n)=3^n$

Comment: There's no need for induction for that.

Comment: Well, it is a handy tool here. Is there any reason of not making use of it?

Comment: If you already deduce that $f(n)=3^n$, then we just substitute in lhs and rhs to prove it straight away.
Also, I am interested in how was this formula deduced in the first place.

Comment: How can you show uniqueness ? I can only see it if $f$ is continuous

Comment: @Cauchy. $f(2)=f(1+1)=f(1)f(1)=3^2$ and $f(3)=f(2)f(1)=3^3$ et cetera. This pattern makes us 'suspect' that $f(n)=3^n$. For a full proof of it we can apply induction. This is a very common way of working.

Comment: @Belgi Uniqueness of what? Of $f$? Continuity plays no part in this whatsoever.

Comment: @drhab - yes. Otherwise how can you show that there isn't another function that satisfies the conditions ?

Comment: @belgi I mean to realize now that your question was meant for Cauchy, who (wrongly) stated that substitution on both sides would be enough here to prove that $f(n)=3^n$. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Cauchy Substituting on both sides only confirms that the function $f(n)=3^n$ satisfies the mentioned conditions. However, it does not exclude that there are other functions doing that as well. So it is not a full proof that $f(n)=3^n$.